# How to parse Json object from angularjs return value with another angularjs value returned?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have Json array returned from angularjs function in $rootScope. I get the key of the object to be parsed from another angularjs function. I didn't know how to parse and get the value from the returned json array with the key returned by another function.

**JS function:**

```
$rootScope.json={"test":{"analysis1": {"png": [{"duration": "test", "transfer": "new"}], "afr": [{"duration": "test", "transfer": "new"}]}},"analysis2": {"png": [{"duration": "test", "transfer": "new"}], "afr": [{"duration": "test", "transfer": "new"}]}}

$scope.opt=["analysis1","png"]
```

By using the following code I can get the value by providing static values

**HTML Code:**

```
<div> {$ json.test.analysis1.png $} </div>
```

I need to parse through the json array dynamically in html how to achieve it?

I need to get value dynamically like this ?

```
<div> {$ json.test.{$ opt[0] $}.{$ opt[1] $} $} </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit @Liam

Answer (score -3):

```
$rootScope.json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"test":{"analysis1": {"png": [{"duration": "test", "transfer": "new"}], "afr": [{"duration": "test", "transfer": "new"}]}},"analysis2": {"png": [{"duration": "test", "transfer": "new"}], "afr": [{"duration": "test", "transfer": "new"}]}}));
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Instead, explain what your code does and how/why it may solve the question.